# MySQL count two rows as one

Tags: mysql

I need to count matches in a database.

Input:

```
id_to    id_from
1        2  
2        1  
1        3
3        1
1        4
5        1
```

the 5th and 6th row has only one direction so doesn't count

Sample Output:

```
id_match
1       
2
3
```

So, for 1 (implicit), 2 and 3 there is a reverse match but for 4 and 5 there aren't.

---- EDITED ----

Supposing the table name is "example" and I want to get all matches of id=1 then the SQL query will be:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM
(SELECT id_to FROM example WHERE id_from = 1) as t1,
(SELECT id_from FROM example WHERE id_to = 1) as t2
WHERE t1.id_to = t2.id_from
```

but maybe there is a better way to do it

Comment: Try with Group by id_to in query

Comment: @Leonardo The question is quite unclear to me. What are your table names?

Comment: Are the values of `id_to` and `id_from` always different, or can you also have `id_to=1, id_from=1` ?

Comment: are your fields in the same table?

Comment: @Leonardo Javier 
See if this edit makes sense. If not please modify it to make more sense.

Comment: Supposing the table name is "example" and I want to get all matches of id=1 then the SQL query will be: `"SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT id_to FROM example WHERE id_from = 1) as t1, (SELECT id_from FROM example WHERE id_to = 1) as t2 WHERE t1.id_to = t2.id_from"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_from AS matched_id 
FROM   your_table AS data1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   your_table AS data2 
               WHERE  data1.id_from = data2.id_to 
                      AND data1.id_to = data2.id_from)
```

I've created a demo [here](http://rextester.com/VBASF16832)

Comment: Thanks! this is not what I need, but it returns ALL ids that have at least one match, very interesting